# Data arrives undefined when Fetching a post

Tags: javascript, react-native, express

So I tried to make a registeration form that post Username, password and email adress to my ExpressJs Server and save it, but The Object arrives undefined... here is my JS code in my react app.:

```
let RegDetails = {
     userName: userName,
    password: password,
    email: email
}
let regJSONED = JSON.stringify(RegDetails);


fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    Headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:  {regJSONED},

}).then(data => console.log(data));
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in this code, because when I'm posting with Postman on JSON format the body is arrving as it supposed, but with this fetching the body is arriving like this:

```
{
userName: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  email: undefined
}
```

Can someone help me detect the error?

Comment: try `body :regJSONED` instead of `body:  {regJSONED},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
body:  {regJSONED}
```

...you're setting `body` to an object that looks like this:

```
{regJSONED: {\"userName\":\"joe\",\"password\":\"secret\",\"email\":\"joe@example.com\"}}
```

...which `fetch` then probably converts to a string, most likely `"[object Object]"`.

I think you just wanted to send the string you stored in `regJSONED`; don't wrap it in `{}`:

```
body:  regJSONED
```

---

Also note that with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), `Headers` should be `headers` (all lower case).

---

Also note that `data` in your example will be a `response` object. You need to read the body of the response in order to use it (see [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)). There are also some error handling issues (including [the `fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*).

So probably something like:

```
let regDetails = {
    userName: userName,
    password: password,
    email: email
}
let regJSONED = JSON.stringify(RegDetails);

fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:  regJSONED,

})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text(); // or `.json()` or any of several others, depending on what you expect back
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alot dude!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like typo in header:

```
let RegDetails = {
     userName: userName,
    password: password,
    email: email
}
let regJSONED = JSON.stringify(RegDetails);


fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    header:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:  {regJSONED},

}).then(data => data && console.log(data.json()));
```

Better example see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch